# Compute the Fourier Series of a trig function

Tags: fourier-series

I want to compute the Fourier series for the following function

$$ g_n(\theta) = -2nK_{n}(\theta)\sin(n\theta)$$

where $K_n(\theta)$ is the Fejer Kernel.

I tried to compute the Fourier coefficients directly using this formula for $K_n(\theta)$

$$ K_n(\theta) = \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{\sin^2(\frac{n\theta}{2})} {\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})}\right) $$

Then the coefficients are given by

\begin{align}
c_k & = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g_n(\theta)e^{-ik\theta}d\theta \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(-2n \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{\sin^2(\frac{n\theta}{2})} {\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})}\right)\sin(n\theta)\right)e^{-ik\theta}d\theta \\
& = -\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(\frac{\sin^2(\frac{n\theta}{2})} {\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})}\right)\sin(n\theta)e^{-ik\theta}d\theta \\
\end{align}

I'm not sure how to proceed after this. Can someone give me a hint as to how I should compute this Fourier series?

Comment: Did you try to see if this is an odd or an even function?  It seems the real part may be odd so those parts of those coefficients must vanish.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Given that $K_n$ is an even summability kernel, $g_n$ is indeed odd. I'll try computing just the sine terms.

Comment: because $K_n(\theta) = f(\theta)^2$ and that $f(\theta) = C \sum_{k \le n} e^{i k \theta}$ you get that $K_n(\theta) =  C^2 \sum_{k \le n} |k| e^{i k \theta}$ so that $\sin(n \theta) K_n(\theta) = C^2 / 2i \sum_{k \le n} (|k+n|-|k-n|) e^{i k \theta}$ for some constant $C$

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the significance of index $i$.

Don't you want to compute the $k$th coefficient, which is:
\begin{align}
c_k & = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g_n(\theta)e^{-ik\theta}d\theta \ ?
\end{align}

Comment: You're right, my typo. Thanks!

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment not as an answer.